# Can I perform Verification and validation checks on datasets like AndroPRAguard, Drebin(contain malware and benign mobile apps)?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, feature-selection, feature-engineering, feature-scaling

Verification and validation checks for data:

Verification of data:
- Visual Checks: It checks data visually.

- Double Entry Check: It checks duplication of data in the database.

Validation of data:

- Range Check: It checks whether data falls between specified lower and upper boundaries.
- Format Check: It checks whether the data is in the right format.
- Check digits: It checks valid digits in data.
- Presence Check: It checks whether data has been entered into the correct field.